# Using whereHasMorph inside a local scope for MophByMany relationships

Tags: laravel

I am needing to find out the current players on a given team. I have created a scope for this. The requirements are that it checks a pivot table to see if the left_at field is null or not. If it is Null that means they are still on the team (current player). The relationship is a polymorphic many to many relationship. The reason why it's polymorphic because a team can also have players come and go as well as coaches for the team.

Team.php

```
/**
 * Scope a query to only include current players.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder $query
 */
public function scopeCurrentPlayers($query)
{
    return $query->whereHasMorph('players', Player::class, function ($query) {
        $query->whereNull('left_at');
    });
}

**
 * Get all players that have been members of the stable.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphByMany
 */
public function players()
{
    return $this->morphedByMany(Player::class, 'member')->using(Member::class)->withPivot(['joined_at', 'left_at']);
}
```

Controller

```
$currentTeamPlayers = $team->currentPlayers()->get()->pluck('id');
```

I am expecting to get a collection of current players on the team however I am receiving the following error.

+exception: Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError^ {#5387
      -originalClassName: "TypeError"
      #message: "Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::getBelongsToRelation() must be an instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphTo, instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphToMany given, called in /Users/jeffreydavidson/Projects/Ringside/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/QueriesRelationships.php on line 215"`

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? I just came across this as well.

Comment: Hi Even I came across the same problem. Did you get any solution?

Comment: You already have morphed relation, so your scope could look like:

`public function scopeCurrentPlayers($query)
{
    return $query->whereHas('players', function ($query) {
        $query->whereNull('left_at');
    });
}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`whereHasMorph` function only works for `morphTo` associations. Reference: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-morph-to-relationships

For `morphMany` associations, you can simply use `whereHas`. Reference: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

So in your case,

```php
public function scopeCurrentPlayers($query)
{
    return $query->whereHas('players', Player::class, function ($query) {
        $query->whereNull('left_at');
    });
}
```